# Three.js shader error: Varyings over maximum register limit

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I'm trying to create a virtual multiplayer platform for live concerts using three.js and socket.io.   
While in single-player everything works fine, but when I try to do tests to see if the website could handle a big load of players by creating multiple NPCs at the same time it all falls apart and it gives me these errors:

```
THREE.WebGLProgram: shader error:  0 35715 false gl.getProgramInfoLog Varyings over maximum register limit


THREE.WebGLProgram: shader error:  1282 35715 false gl.getProgramInfoLog Varyings over maximum register limit
```

The error comes up when I create more then 8 NPCs using this for loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        var x,y,z;
        x = Math.random() * 2000;
        x *= Math.round(Math.random()) ? 1 : -1;
        z = Math.random() * (19000-8000)+8000;
        let smurf = new Npc(this, this.options, "Groupie", x, -190, -z, false, "Fan");
        this.npcs.push(smurf);
        this.remoteNPCsColliders.push(smurf);
    }
```

From what I've understood through the three.js documentation, the issue consists of passing too many varyings at the same time, but at the same time it seems that varyings are additional data from shaders, which are not used in my code. This is the NPC object code:

```
class Npc {
  constructor(game, options, identifier, x, y, z, conv, type) {
    let model, colour;

    const colours = ['Black', 'Brown', 'White'];
    colour = colours[Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length)];

    if (options === undefined) {
      const people = ['BeachBabe', 'BusinessMan', 'Doctor', 'FireFighter', 'Housewife', 'Policeman', 'Prostitute', 'Punk', 'RiotCop', 'Roadworker', 'Robber', 'Sheriff', 'Streetman', 'Waitress'];
      model = people[Math.floor(Math.random() * people.length)];
    }
    this.model = model;
    this.colour = colour;
    this.game = game;
    this.animations = this.game.animations;

    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(100, 300, 100);
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      visible: false
    });
    const box = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    box.name = "Collider";
    box.position.set(0, 150, 0);
    this.collider = box;

    const loader = new FBXLoader();
    const npc = this;


    loader.load(`${game.assetsPath}fbx/people/${type}.fbx`, function(object) {

      object.mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(object);
      npc.root = object;
      npc.mixer = object.mixer;

      object.name = identifier;
      object.conv = conv;

      object.traverse(function(child) {
        if (child.isMesh) {
          child.castShadow = true;
          child.receiveShadow = true;
        }
      });

      const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

      npc.object = new THREE.Object3D();
      npc.object.position.set(x, y, z);
      //npc.object.position.set(0, 0, 0);
      npc.object.rotation.set(0, -Math.PI / 2, 0);
      npc.object.scale.set(2.3, 2.3, 2.3);

      npc.object.add(object);
      if (npc.deleted === undefined) game.scene.add(npc.object);

      npc.object.add(box);

      //if (game.animations.Idle!==undefined) npc.action = "Happy";
      npc.action = object.animations[0]
    });
  }
    set action(name){
        //Make a copy of the clip if this is a remote player
        if (this.actionName == name) return;
        const clip = this.animations[name];
        const action = this.mixer.clipAction( name );
        action.time = 0;
        this.mixer.stopAllAction();
        
        action.startAt(0.03333);
        this.actionName = name;
        this.actionTime = Date.now();

        action.fadeIn(0.5);
        action.play();
    }
    get action(){
        return this.actionName;
    }
}
```

I've tried commenting every bit of code in here but with no success. The only thing that fixed the error was disabling the shadow map of the renderer, but that for some reason overexposed the whole map and made everything unplayable.
The only other questions on the topic that I could find put the problem on the lights, which I guess could be an explanation since disabling the shadow map fixed the error, but I've disabled every single light and the error still occurs.
I'm literally going crazy over this, I hope that someone can help me!